# Insert new column that adds a series from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have a table with dates and follower growth for each date and want to make a new column that depicts total followers gained.

How can I insert a new column that basically adds the 'new followers' column in to a summation series?

```
date    | new followers
-----------------------    
1/1/15 |    1
1/2/15 |    3
1/3/15 |    5
1/4/15 |    4
1/5/15 |    3
```

New table would look like

```
date    | new followers | total followers gained
------------------------------------------------
1/1/15  |   1           |    1
1/2/15  |   3           |    4
1/3/15  |   5           |    9
1/4/15  |   4           |   13
1/5/15  |   3           |   16
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL?  They are different.

Comment: sql server. question is what commands i'd need for my new column 'total followers gained'

Comment: What version of SQL Server? So know which duplicate target is best.

Comment: Why add this as a value in the table when it can be computed just as easily?  I believe you're looking for a [Running total](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 0):

This SQL will accomplish what you want with a Select. If it is really necessary to persist this value in a table, then you could use this SQL in a trigger. But since you could just calculate this amount on the fly, I'm not sure why you would persist it.

```
declare @tempTable table (theDt datetime, newFollowers int)

insert into @tempTable
select '1/1/15',1
UNION select '1/2/15',3
UNION select '1/3/15',5
UNION select '1/4/15',4
UNION select '1/5/15',3

select t1.theDt, 
       t1.newFollowers + SUM(case when t2.theDt IS not null then t2.newFollowers else 0 end) as "Total Followers"
from @tempTable t1
left outer join @tempTable t2 on t1.theDt > t2.theDt
group by t1.theDt, t1.newFollowers
order by t1.theDt
```